# How to create an instance on EC2 with all customizations (libs,folders) from another instance

Tags: ec2-ami, ec2-api-tools

I am new to EC2. The way I am attempting to do this is: 1) create a snapshot from instance1 ; 2) create a volume from snapshot; 3) attach the volume to instance2

when I ssh to instance2 it is still the basic instance without my folders and customizations. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an AMI from the Instance 1. [Here](https://robpickering.com/2010/07/create-a-full-backup-image-of-your-amazon-ec2-instance-2-129) Is a link to a tutorial on how to do it. You might also check for Amazon directions on how to do it. They're usually about 80% complete with about 10% of the background information you need, but you can do it with their directions.